# Mips executable does not have relocation section

Tags: linux, elf, mips32, relocation

I was trying to understand the way an ELF executes in various architectures.But when I was studying the MIPS-II ELF 32-bit LSB executable via Readelf ,I found out that there was no relocation section in my executable file.Can anyone explain to me how does it execute without relocation section.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it is an executable, *e_type == ET_EXEC*, then it has already been relocated by the linker. Typically, object files, *e_type == ET_REL*, are relocatable and have SHT_RELA or SHT_REL sections. The OS loader, *binfmt_elf* on Linux, doesn't do any relocation.